# Obtener ultima iteracion en un for of

Tags: javascript

En una sentencia `for` sería de esta forma:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (i === data.length - 1) {
    console.log("es la ultima ")
  } else {
    console.log("No es la ultima")
  }
  // cosas...
}
```

Pero ¿cómo puedo obtener la última iteración usando una sentencia `for ... of`?

Answer (score 3):

Como no especificas qué tipo de objeto pretendes iterar, será difícil darte una respuesta única.

En tu pregunta veo que usas la propiedad `length` del objeto iterable, esto nos da una pista de que puedes estar iterando alguno de los siguientes objetos:

- [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String)
- [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array)
- [`TypedArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/TypedArray)
- [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList)
- [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/arguments)

Una forma de usar dicha propiedad para saber cuando estás en la última iteración puede ser la siguiente:

```js
let myIterable = [1,2,3,4,5];
let iteracion = 0;

for(let element of myIterable) {
  iteracion++;
  console.log(`Iteración número: ${iteracion}`);
  if(iteracion === myIterable.length) {
    console.log('Esta es la última iteración sobre el objeto iterable');
  }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Como puedes ver, voy a iterar sobre un tipo `Array`. He creado una variable fuera del bucle a la cual he llamado `iteracion` y la he iniciado en 0. En cada iteración se aumenta el valor de dicha variable y se compara con el valor devuelto por la propiedad `length` del obejto iterable. De esta forma, cuando ambos valores coincidan significa que es la última iteración.

No es la única forma, y dependerá también del tipo de objeto que estés iterando.

Puedes leer la documentación de la sentencia [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...of) como referencia.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta fue de gran ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Si tu iterable es un array, el método `array.entries()` te devuelve en cada iteración una pareja `[indice, valor]`. Puedes usar la parte `indice` para saber si es el último, y la parte `valor` para lo que necesites. Es decir:

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

for ([i, element] of array1.entries()) { 
  if (i==array1.length-1) {
     ultimo = "es el último";
  } else {
     ultimo = "no es el último";
  }
  console.log(element, ultimo); 
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, fue de gran ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Sin una propiedad que lo indique (como `length`), **no podemos saber de antemano cual es la última iteración**.

El loop `for..of` podŕia no tener último elemento (podŕia ser infinito), lo que hace el loop es llamar a la función `.next()`, dicho de otro modo, la iteración y la cantidad de elementos no tienen necesariamente relación. Lo que le indica al loop que tiene que dejar de iterar es la propiedad `done` del objeto que retorna `.next()`.

Es decir: cuando  `for...of` comienza a iterar, no sabe cuando va a terminar. Termina cuando `done` es `true`.

Ejemplo:

```js
const obj1 = {}

obj1[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  let i = 0;
  while(i<=3){// <-- podŕia ser true y es infinito
    yield ["a",i++];  
  }
};

var iterator = obj1[Symbol.iterator]();

console.log(iterator.next().done);// 1 elemento 
console.log(iterator.next().done);// 2 elementos
console.log(iterator.next().done);// 3 elementos
console.log(iterator.next().done);// 4 elementos 
console.log(iterator.next().done);// no hay mas
```

Dicho esto, la opción para saber cual es la cantidad de elementos (si no tiene la propiedad `lenght`) es iterandolo completo y contando la cantidad de iteraciones. Es decir, **la última iteración solo se conoce al final de una iteración completa**.

```js
const obj1 = {}

obj1[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  let i = 0;
  while(i<=3){
    yield ["a",i++];  
  }
};

var iterator = obj1[Symbol.iterator]();

let length = -1;
let termino = false;
while(!termino){//<-- termina cuando .done es true
  length++;
  termino = iterator.next().done;
}

console.log("El objeto tiene "+length+" elementos");
```

Como podrán ver, el objeto está vacío en realidad, esto quiere decir que el iterador no tiene una relación necesaria con la cantidad de elementos. Pero cada iteración retorna un valor que podemos entender que es un elemento.

Los ejemplos anteriores con un `for of` serían:

```js
const obj1 = {}

obj1[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
  let i = 0;
  while(i<=3){
    yield ["a",i++];  
  }
};

var iterator = obj1[Symbol.iterator]();

for(let p of obj1){
  console.log(p)
}
```